# Is there a way to revert OSX Snowleopard to a clean fresh install?

Tags: snow-leopard

My mums laptop is not very well managed and I would like to clean it up and perform a fresh install on it and teach her the ropes from scratch as she is having a lot of performance problems with it at the moment.

Is there anyway i can reinstall it?

It is a Macbook Pro

Comment: Do you still have the installation DVD?

Comment: I don't think it came with one. It was preinstalled.

Answer (score 2):

If you bought your Macbook new then it should have come with a set of recover DVD's that look like this :

[image: recover dvd set]

You need to locate this media and use the disk marked "Mac OS X Install DVD" to reinstall the OS. Remember to take a backup of all user data beforehand.

Comment: I don't think it came with these CD's. I bought one for myself two months ago and i didn't get this with it. Both were bought new from the Official Apple store near me.

Comment: Yours may have come with Lion, for which no recovery media is included because you are supposed to use the new Lion recovery partition. All macs prior to Lion shipped with a booklet containing CD/DVD's. If for some reason it's missing I recommend going back to the Apple store explaining the situation and asking for a Macbook Pro SL install disk. They may just give you a replacement set (because it's locked to hardware it's not like giving away a retail version.) Otherwise you may have to buy the retail DVD, go secondhand or go to a website of low moral fiber.

Answer (score 0):

The OS is preisnatalled, but all new MacBook Pros with original OS version of Snow Leopard or below come with install DVD (pictured in another answer). *Note that that's not the case for Lion.*

If you didn't buy the machine new or if you have lost the install DVD you could try to find someone who has Macbook Pro from the same year and with the same screen size and use that install DVD. Some later years may also work, but it is not guaranteed.

If you want to and could use Lion (see [requirements](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html)) instead of Snow Leopard, you could install Lion on top of SL via the App Store.app (that costs $29), burn [install DVD](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/08/create-burn-bootable-mac-os-x-lion-install-disc/) or make [install USB](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/) in the process and then [do a clean install of Lion](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/21/mac-os-x-lion-clean-install-explained/). Alternatively, you can buy Lion USB drive from Apple (more expensive) and do clean install from there.

Edit: it appears that you may but [Snow Leopard install DVD](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A)

Whatever install/reinstall you do, remember to **back up your data** prior to that.

Comment: Can i buy an Lion CD and reinstall with that?

Comment: Not a CD, but USB drive directly from Apple: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD256Z/A; it can be used the same way as install CD. It is more expensive than downloading Lion and creating install CD on your own; but it is much easier.

Comment: Actually it appears that you may even but Snow Leopard DVD: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A