# Simplest and safest way to do a clean install of a newer MacOS? I currently have El Capitan, but no DVDs

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

- I have a MacBook Air 13-inch, Mid 2012 running OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 and would like to do a clean install of a "more modern" MacOS.
- I have read about [recent certificate problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/143729) but that discussion is over my head.
- I have seen [images of install DVDs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48667/143729) but I have none now and don't remember ever seeing any.
- I have already backed up all my files.

What is the simplest, safest way that I can do a *clean install* of a newer (or newest) MacOS? Do I need an AppleID for this? [There is an Apple store here](https://www.apple.com/tw/retail/taipei101/) but they don't seem to want to do repair work on my computer because it has been obsoleted. However, they might still be able to offer some help I can't do this myself.

Comment: Are you able to download the macOS installer you prefer from the App Store App today? If so, you can sidestep just about all the issues you mention. Not sure if you have ruled out that option. (So jealous you’re near 101 - I would love a weekend or longer there to visit)

Comment: No I don't think I've ruled that out. I suppose I will need an Apple ID? I'd forgotten my original password and there is no longer a recovery procedure for forgotten passwords. I've never actually used the App Store before, but if it is that simple and it implements a clean install, then this will be easier than I'd expected.  Oh, the 101 is packed and crazy-busy on the weekends with tourists. Never go there on weekends @@!

Comment: I would go there to see the crowd (@@! the crowd) and not get anything done (LOL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, it seems you need an overview of how to do this. All macos versions from the App Store have a built in utility section where you can open terminal and run createosinstaller script to make a bootable USB installer from the downloaded installer app. Most do not require an AppleID in the App Store, but you might have to set that up as well. You’ll want one, so be sure you write down your security questions and be prepared to enter payment info if requested. It won’t be charged, but you will have to enter it if your machine doesn’t let you make a payment-free account as part of your first free app download.

You do need a USB drive that will be wiped totally - 8 GB is probably large enough, 16 for sure is enough. It doesn’t need to be fast, just needs to work well enough to store 5+ GB of new data and be erased one time.

Here goes:

1. I recommend the newest OS you can - so open the App Store and try to download Catalina.
2. If that fails, you’ll need to check the requirements for your mac: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210222 _(hint both models of 2012 Air are eligible for Catalina, so you don’t need to use the next step unless you need an older OS)
3. Then get the installer that’s older than Catalina but meets your requirements - [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Once the installer is downloaded, follow Apple instructions to make the bootable USB: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

When you boot from recovery (try booting from internet recovery just in case your 2012 model can internet boot - you can skip everything above)

Either way, choose the erase install path in this document whether you internet boot or recovery boot or make USB installer:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: This is great; *exactly* what I needed. I'll try this tonight, thank you!

Comment: I'd planned to try this out right away and then accept, but didn't, so accepting anyway, thanks! :-)